# fixing the way how to sort element in a list using python sorted method

Tags: python, list, sorting, sortedlist

I have this list containing the following images with these the name structure "number.image"

- The list stores the elements of a local folder based on a path.

```
[1.image, 2.image, 3.image, 4.image, 5.image, 6.image, 7.image, 8.image, 9.image, 10.image, 11.image, 12.image, 13.image]
```

applying the python build-in `sorted()` method to make sure the elements in the list are sorted in proper manner I got this result. As you see the order is not correct.

```
1.image 
10.image
11.image
12.image
13.image
2.image
3.image
4.image
5.image
6.image
7.image
8.image
9.image
```

Comment: Use natsort https://pypi.org/project/natsort/

Comment: It is because of the built-in sort that are sorting by lexicographical order.

You can try this code out.

```
image_list = ['1.image', '10.image', '11.image', '12.image', '13.image', '2.image', '3.image', '4.image', '5.image', '6.image', '7.image', '8.image', '9.image']

sorted_image_list = sorted(image_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

print(sorted_image_list)

```

Comment: @LoopFree Couple readability nits: 1) Prefer not to use [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) when defining variables in Python 2) Using  `f` for the file seems more appropriate here than `x`, which is often used when the variable represents a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the inbuilt [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function and not install a third-party library such as [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/), you can use a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) for the key argument that interprets the stem of the file as an integer:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> filenames = [
...     '1.image',
...     '10.image',
...     '11.image',
...     '12.image',
...     '13.image',
...     '2.image',
...     '3.image',
...     '4.image',
...     '5.image',
...     '6.image',
...     '7.image',
...     '8.image',
...     '9.image',
... ]
>>> sorted_filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda f: int(Path(f).stem))
>>> # Arguably less readable alternative using list indexing  splitting on the period manually: 
>>> # sorted_filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda f: int(f.split('.')[0]))
>>> print('\n'.join(sorted_filenames))
1.image
2.image
3.image
4.image
5.image
6.image
7.image
8.image
9.image
10.image
11.image
12.image
13.image
```